# How to upload image from windows form picturbox to FTP server?

Tags: c#

I have a form with a picturebox. At first i load the picturebox with picture from my local pc. Now i want to upload the picture to a ftp server.

I don't understand how to get the filepath of picturebox. Or is there any other way?

```
public void UploadImage(PictureBox image, string filename)
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
   client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsername, ftpPassword);
 client.UploadFile("ftp://127.0.0.1/Image/",WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile);

   }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get first file path of image that is in your picture box

```
string filepath = image.ImageLocation;
```

And then pass this path to `WebClient.UploadFile` like

```
public void UploadImage(PictureBox image, string filename)
{
    string filepath = image.ImageLocation;     //<= Get image path 

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsername, ftpPassword);
        client.UploadFile("ftp://127.0.0.1/Image/", filepath);    //<= Pass this path here

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok... I tried to direct upload the image to FTP server. But I think it is not possible. So first I save the image to a local folder and then upload the image from local folder to ftp server. Finally problem is solved. Thank you. @er-sho

Comment: Glad to hear, then please mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green :)